# Symbolicating Crash Report ios

Tags: ios, xcode, symbolicate, otool

Along with crash report, I've .app and .dSYM package as well. I'm trying to symbolicate the crash report by running the following command

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash crash.crash > SymbolicatedPaperio.crash`

The first few lines of exception stack trace looks like,

`Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001898a61c0 0x189777000 + 1241536
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001882e055c 0x1882d8000 + 34140
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001898a6094 0x189777000 + 1241236
3   Foundation                          0x000000018a333808 0x18a285000 + 714760
4   UIKit                               0x000000018f984848 0x18f6f1000 + 2701384
5   UIKit                               0x000000018f9a4fac 0x18f6f1000 + 2834348
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001898537dc 0x189777000 + 903132
7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018985140c 0x189777000 + 893964
8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000189780068 0x189777000 + 36968
9   paperio                             0x00000001000b0d80 0x1000a4000 + 52608
10  paperio                             0x00000001000bf0fc 0x1000a4000 + 110844
11  UIKit                               0x000000018f768f3c 0x18f6f1000 + 491324
12  UIKit                               0x000000018f987158 0x18f6f1000 + 2711896
13  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000018b4365e8 0x18b413000 + 144872
14  Foundation                          0x000000018a345794 0x18a285000 + 788372
15  BaseBoard                           0x000000018b3b0f00 0x18b37e000 + 208640
16  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000018b4306a8 0x18b413000 + 120488
17  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000018b4363c4 0x18b413000 + 144324
18  UIKit                               0x000000018f9885c0 0x18f6f1000 + 2717120
19  UIKit                               0x000000018f988264 0x18f6f1000 + 2716260
20  UIKit                               0x000000018fcb9ba4 0x18f6f1000 + 6065060`

For the first line, on my mac, it is not symbolicated and the output remains same (as the non-symbolicated line above). However, on a different mac, I can see the output as:

`0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001898a61c0 __exceptionPreprocess + 124`

This is happening for all the frameworks and libraries. Want to understand what possibly could be missing on my mac - that its not symbolicating properly and how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, to symbolicate libraries and framework's method, we need to have symbols for the iOS version for which crash was generated. These are (by default) present in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode\iOS DeviceSupport`. So, if the symbol for correct iOS version is not present here - the symbolicator would not be able to properly decrypt the reports.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the location of the Archive file：

```
./symbolicatecrash crashPath archivePath > output
```